# Ordnance Survey Master Map font in QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, font, os-mastermap

I have been trying to style some OSMM data using [their supplied QML files](https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/OSMM-Topography-Layer-stylesheets) which include a font with some of their symbology in. I've added the font to my system (ubuntu 14.04 LTS) and when viewed in FontMatrix and other system font tools it looks fine:

[image]

But when I come to use it in QGIS the font has no glyphs visible and I end up with ugly rectangles instead of my symbols.

[image]

Is there some trick to get QGIS to recognise this font?

Comment: The qml/sld - files from github are somehow not right. Qgis tells me some lines/positions that are incorrect. For example there is data-pjax-transient in tags without a value. I think there the ="true" was forgotten several times. As well as other tag-mismatches. The ones directly from OSMM are working. But to your question :) Are the truetype fonts that were delivered in the system folder? (/usr/share/fonts/truetype)

Comment: Yes, i've tried it in both ~/.local/share/fonts/OSMasterMap.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/maps/OSMasterMap.ttf (and done fc-cache -fv)

Comment: Just trying again, and i realized that the .ttf is wrong as well. I got the one from https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/resources/carto-design/cartographic-stylesheets.html directly, not via github, and they are working.

Comment: cmp (and diff) think they are identical

Comment: Just tried again on a debian sytem, and it got the same problems there. Maybe because of the freetype renderer that debian/ubuntu is using instead of truetype. Sry for your time